# lattice vibration

Tags: solid-state-physics

I would  like  to  inquire  about  acoustic and  optical branch in Phonons vibration; 
My question is:
what is  the  physics description when we say what is  make  acoustic  and  optical branch appear in lattice  vibration

Comment: Wikipedia gives a pretty good description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#Acoustic_and_optical_phonons

Comment: Your question is not clear in terms of language... Can you restate it correctly?

Comment: why  crystal  produce  optical  branch and  acoustic  branch ?

Comment: what  is the  physical  reason  that  make acoustic  branch appear or  optical branch.

Answer (score 1):

Acoustic branch arises from the relative motion of the unit cells, while an optical branch is due to the relative motion of atoms within a unit cell. The number of acoustic branches is always fixed at 3 (number of spatial directions). The number of optical branches ranges from 0 (1 atom in the basis) to unlimited, in principle.